# Changing text of SMJobBless dialog

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication, modal-dialog

I want to run a privileged helper tool as a one-off thing when required, and I'm using [SMJobBless](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ServiceManagement/Reference/ServiceManagement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) to do this. However, the text and button of the authorization dialog box imply that the app is trying to install a helper tool, perhaps one that may permanently run in the background ([screenshot](http://d.pr/i/VX3V)). But I don't want users to get the wrong impression. So is there any way to get the old type of dialog box back, which simply said: `<App> wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this.`? I understand that for security reasons Apple wouldn't allow customizing the text, but it should at least allow reverting to the old-style  dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done while creating the `AuthorizationRef` by using `kAuthorizationEnvironmentPrompt`.